# How to modify spatialite table column names with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I am trying to modify column names in a SpatiaLite table.
To do that, I run the following SQL statements in the DB Manager :

```
-- Rename existing table
ALTER TABLE compteur_routier RENAME TO compteur_routier_sav;

-- Create new table with modified column names
CREATE TABLE compteur_routier (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
geom POINT,
id_compt TEXT,
type_compt TEXT,
angle INTEGER,
id_tmp INTEGER
);

-- Insert data from renamed table
INSERT INTO compteur_routier(id, geom, id_compt, type_compt, angle, id_tmp)
SELECT id, geom, id_compteur, type_compteur, angle, id_tmp FROM compteur_routier_sav;

-- Drop renamed table
DROP TABLE compteur_routier_sav;
```

This works perfectly in the DB manager, column names are modified and datas are kept.
However, when I load the resulting table in QGIS and open the attribute table, I get old column names and datas replaced by column names.

Table before :
[image: table before]

Table after :
[image: table after]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to QGIS and SpatiaLite devs, I finally managed to understand what was wrong in my queries : create table with spatial column without using AddGeometryColumn statement.
The proper workflow is the following :

```
-- Create a copy of the table with data
SELECT CloneTable('main', 'compteur_routier', 'compteur_routier_sav', 1);

-- Drop old table (administration tables will be adapted)
SELECT DropGeoTable('compteur_routier');

-- Create and fill new table from cloned table
-- Create new table with modified column names, WITHOUT geom column
CREATE TABLE compteur_routier (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
id_compt TEXT,
type_compt TEXT,
angle INTEGER,
id_tmp INTEGER
);

-- Add geom column
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('compteur_routier', 'geom', 2154, 'POINT', 'XY', 1);
SELECT CreateSpatialIndex('compteur_routier', 'geom');

-- Insert data from renamed table
INSERT INTO compteur_routier(id, geom, id_compt, type_compt, angle, id_tmp)
SELECT id, geom, id_compteur, type_compteur, angle, id_tmp FROM compteur_routier_sav;
SELECT UpdateLayerStatitics('compteur_routier', 'geom');

-- Drop cloned table (administration tables will be adapted)
SELECT DropGeoTable('compteur_routier_sav'); -- QGIS 3.4.1
```

Note : DropGeoTable should be replaced by DropTable when SpatiaLite lib will be updated in QGIS.
For more detailed information :

[QGIS issue](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19598)

[SpatiaLite ticket](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/tktview/e8d83559fbc5d492ff1dff86e07751547b485430)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried renaming the columns in QGIS using the Properties dialog box? (Right click on spatialite layer > Properties > Source Fields > enable editing, double click on layer name, rename > save layer edits)

You won't be able to rename the pkey column or anything associated with a trigger, but others should be fine (tested in QGIS 3.2)[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, after having enabled editing, I still can't rename any column... Also, the delete column button is greyed. I tested this on several spatialite databases/layers...

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using? This was not available in previous versions as it is indeed not straightforward to delete and rename columns in sqlite/spatialite; newer versions have incorporated a workaround to make it possible from the GUI. I recommend using 3.x if you aren't already. Try re-loading your spatialite layer using the Add Spatialite Layer option (when you hover over the layer in the layer panel, ideally there should not be an sql= expression when showing the layer source)

Comment: I definitely use QGIS 3.2, on W10, but still can't get rename and delete column options active...

Comment: Also tested with QGIS 3.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 : same results with DB Manager, column rename and delete still inactive in layer properties dialog.

Comment: You have tried different ways of loading the spatialite layer?

Comment: Yes, I tried from browser panel, from datasource manager and from DB manager.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it and there was no such thing as you said. I think it should be that your SQL is not getting it right. At the time, I found out that for SpatiaLite, if you use the method you used, the geometry will be lost after executing the "ALTER TABLE compteur_routier RENAME TO compteur_routier_sav;" statement. The SQL statement you use is only for SQLite without geometry.

You can use the Refactor fields tool. 
But when I tested in QGIS 3.2.1, I found that if I use the Refactor fields tool to convert to another SpatiaLite table, I get a failed to check metadata error. The generated SpatialLite table cannot be used. You can use the Refactor fields tool to generate a Shapefile and then export the Shapefile as a SpatiaLite table.I tested it in QGIS 3.2.1.

Comment: Generate a shapefile is not an option, I precisely try to modify the original Spatialite table. I am aware of the fact that geometry metadata are not handled by my SQL query, but I thought they would be kept as the table name remains the same...